# Which <ul> has the most <li>s?

Tags: php, html-lists

I simply want to search that which `<ul>` has the most `<li>`?  How would I do that?

Like there's an html page containing

```
<ul>
<li>1</li>
</ul>

<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>1</li>
<li>1</li>
</ul>

<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>1</li>
</ul>
```

Now then I want to show `<ul>` number 2 has the most `<li>`s. It can be done via PHP.

Thanks

Comment: In what format do you have this page? Is it in a string? Is it an XML document object?

Comment: If it is already in HTML should you not using javascript ?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to use jQuery for this - it may loo like this

```
var largestUl = null;

$('ul').each(function () {
    if (largestUl == null) {
        largestUl = this;
    } else {
        if ($(largestUl, 'li').length > $(largestUl, 'li').length) {
            largestUl = this;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: the question is tagged php. not javascript